# pandas read_excel() reads nothing and there's no error message

Tags: python, excel

Since there's no error message, I am actually not completely sure how to google this...

I tried googling with questions like "python read_excel reads nothing" or "pandas read_excel() outputs blank" or something alike, but have not found anything useful. Hence I'm turning to this community for help, again.

Basically I have an excel file, that has 71 columns and thousands of rows. I am currently using the following line to read my data:

```
data_my = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(base_dir, input_file), sheet_name='happy')
```

and when I try to print the column names:

```
print(data_my.columns.names)
```

I get:

```
[None]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am really not sure what is going on. There's no error, so my file path is correct and there is a sheet named "happy" in my file. But why is there nothing read into my object `data_my`?

Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the frame in `data_my` but are accessing `data_Audit`. What happens when you print `data_my` after the `read_excel` command?

Comment: my apology. i forgot to change the object name for the 2nd line. it's fixed! and i am indeed printing the column name from the same data object.

Comment: What was the output when you printed data_my after read_excel?

Comment: it was empty.... HOWEVER. i made some changes and then control z couple times and somehow, the SAME code now works.... thanks a lot for trying to help though!